# how can I build a reactive app for choosing the starting values for exponential fit equation?

Tags: r, shiny, curve-fitting, exponential

model equation:

```r
y = H0_1 * (1 - exp(- (Tmax / beta) ^ theta)) + c
```

Hello, What I'm trying to do is plot an exponential best-fit curve to the data. I'm trying to make my first shiny app with a slider input for a number of bins to get the starting values. However, when I run the code it doesn't show any graph. The code:

```
x <- Tmax <- 443, 454, 451, 438, 451, 452, 453, 454, 453, 445, 449, 449, 454
y <- HI <- 43, 62, 63, 95, 105, 117.51, 119.07, 122, 122, 125, 131.8, 137, 139

#save this script as app.R
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(

Application title
titlePanel("Exponential Equation App"),

Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
sliderInput(inputId = "H0_1",label = "H0_1:",
min = 100,max = 1000,value = 100, step = 0.5),
sliderInput(inputId = "beta",label = "beta",
min = 300,max = 600,value = 300, step = 0.5),
sliderInput(inputId = "theta",label = "theta",
min = -200,max = -1,value = -5, step = 1),
sliderInput(inputId = "c",label = "c",
min = 0,max = 100,value = 0, step = 1)

    ),


mainPanel(
plotOutput("lineplot")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

output$lineplot <- renderPlot({
x <- seq(from = 427, to = 458, by = 1)
y <-  H0_1 * (1 - exp(- (Tmax / beta) ^ theta)) + c 

plot(x,y, col="red", lwd = 3, type = "l")
lines(y~For_RStudio$Tmax, col="blue", lwd=3)
legend("topleft",c("real data","constructed"), 
col=c("blue","red"), lwd=3)


  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me that you are not using any of your defined slider inputs in your server function.
Try using them with `input$H0_1` instead of just writing `H0_1`.

This means, this line in your server logic

```r
y <-  H0_1 * (1 - exp(- (Tmax / beta) ^ theta)) + c
```

should be

```r
y <-  input$H0_1 * (1 - exp(- (Tmax / input$beta) ^ input$theta)) + input$c
```

##### Edit 1

Here is an app that is at least running. I am clueless of the goal that your app should achieve, aka I don't know how you choose the start values for exp. fit equation. But from the technical side, this is a running app and you can modify it in a way, that makes it work.

what I did:

- created distinction between `x_real`, `y_real` for observed data and `x_constr`, `y_constr` for constructed data.
- moved the definition of the real data inside the server function, but not inside the plot output reactive context.
- put the constructed data inside the reactive plot output context, as it should be changing when input changes - at least I am assuming this.
- added spaces after comma `,`  and around `=` for legibility and because it is good tone

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Exponential Equation App"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "H0_1",label = "H0_1:",
                  min = 100,max = 1000,value = 100, step = 0.5),
      sliderInput(inputId = "beta",label = "beta",
                  min = 300,max = 600,value = 300, step = 0.5),
      sliderInput(inputId = "theta",label = "theta",
                  min = -200,max = -1,value = -5, step = 1),
      sliderInput(inputId = "c",label = "c",
                  min = 0,max = 100,value = 0, step = 1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("lineplot")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  x_real <- c(443, 454, 451, 438, 451, 452, 453, 454, 453, 445, 449, 449, 454)
  y_real <- c(43, 62, 63, 95, 105, 117.51, 119.07, 122, 122, 125, 131.8, 137, 139)
  
  output$lineplot <- renderPlot({
    x_constr <- seq(from = 427, to = 458, by = 1)
    y_constr <-  input$H0_1 * (1 - exp(- (x_constr / input$beta) ^ input$theta)) + input$c 
    #y_real <-  input$H0_1 * (1 - exp(- (x_real / input$beta) ^ input$theta)) + input$c 
    
    plot(x_constr, y_constr, col = "red", lwd = 3, type = "l")
    lines(y_real ~ x_real, col = "blue", lwd = 3)
    legend("topleft", c("real data", "constructed"),
           col = c("blue", "red"), lwd = 3)
    
    
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, tried:  y <-  input$H0_1 * (1 - exp(- (data$Tmax / input$beta) ^ input$theta)) + input$c  but getting an error: 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Comment: From your script, I can not see where `data$Tmax` is defined or where it is coming from. Please take the time to make the example reproducible.

Comment: data is an excel sheet containing two column (Tmax, HI). should it be defined within the script?

Comment: does it work if you substitute `data$Tmax` with just `Tmax`? You have defined `Tmax` in the first line, you just have not defined `data$Tmax`. I suspect you added it because I said you'd have to define `Tmax` but I overlooked it in the first line.

Comment: it doesn't work when I substitute data$Tmax with just Tmax. Tmax is a variable that read from the measured data.

Comment: Honestly, I do not know how to choose the starting values for a exponential fit equation. But I know one thing: Your script is confusing, because in the top you are defining 'real' data and call it `x` and `y`, and later on you construct data, and call it `x` and `y`. Then you want to plot 'real' vs 'constructed' data. Also: you forgot to use `c()` in the first two lines and some text is not commented out ("App Title"). I expect that you put in some minimum effort to present reproducible code! Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: The `lengths differ` error comes because in the creation of `y` (inside server function) you use `Tmax` which has length 13, so the resulting vector has length 13 as well, but then you want to plot it with `x <- seq(...)` which has length 32? This will not work, so clearly you mixed some `x` and `y` up. I recommend that you use unique and understandable names, such as `x_real` and `y_real` for real data, `x_constr` and `y_constr` for constructed data.